# switching from tabbar to a single table view and return to back on row select

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I am creating a Tabbar application as shown.

[image]

On selecting the county a tab bar is shown as follows:

[image]

Now i wish to change to another county...currently there is just one...but there are many..

[image]

I get the following screen when i push on didselectRowatIndex method 
[image]

I tried hiding the tabbar but it increases the complexity of my program and it slows down considerably.

Please can any one guide me in the correct direction as to how to handle this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when i push on didselectRowatIndex"

on `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`, lets assume you have made `Tab2Controller`

dont do PUSH, do a `[self presentModalViewController:Tab2Controller animated:NO];`

to comeback, you do: `[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewController:NO];`

hope this helps..!!
Best of Luck!!

Comment: i tried presentModalViewController to display my tabbar controller class modally. it works fine but when i add a bar button to my local navigation controller in my tabbar controller class it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS. how can i dismiss the tabbar modal.

Comment: i m facing some problems with this method. What i did was on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i created a UINavigation object say `mynav` and `initWithRootViewController` with `showTab` which is my ShowTabbar class object. In ShowTabbar class i created a bar button and did a `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=myButton`. This gets added to my current class navigation controller. Next i made a UITabBarController object and added my BuyerViewController class to it. But the buyerViewController object is not in navigationControl so i cant navigate to next page. Any thoughts..

Answer (score 0):

If I were designing this app I would start with a TableViewController inside a NavigationController and push a UITabBarController via a segue when the row is selected. The back button (in the NavigationController) would be labelled something like "County". Then you don't need a Select County tab. Everything else is the same as you have it.

I have an app using exactly this configuration and it works quite smoothly...almost like Apple intended it ;-)

Note that if you want to save anything about the TabBarController you'll need to communicate it back to your delegate, as the segue instantiates a new tabBarController (you can't re-use one stuffed into a property).

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: I tried your way of keeping a back button but when i push my table view 2 navigation bars are getting displayed one when as i push the table and the second i am setting for my tabbar. How to handle this. I am making my tab bar pragmatically. I need navigation on these tabbar pages hence i have put them inside a local navigation controller for which i think, the second navigation bar is displayed...any thoughts

Comment: You can do what samfisher suggests, that is a good way to keep the ownership chain clear.  Alternatively your VC structure looks like this:  UINavigationController (never displayed) -> UITableViewController (root view controller) -> UITabBarController (instantiated via a segue OR displayed modally by the UITableViewController). The segue will put it inside the navigation controller with the back button. Displaying modally, I'm not sure if you get that back button by default (I think you do). You definitely should NOT have 2 navigation controllers instantiated. Good luck.